# UVM -Create my own macros

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I want to use the following macro in uvm project

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
//   General macros which contain sequence repeate
//   in many places.
//---------------------------------------------------------

`ifndef MY_MACROS_SV
`define MY_MACROS_SV
// MACRO: 'my_fatal_err
//
// calls uvm_fatal in case the assertion is not correct

`define my_fatal(id, msg )
      assert (file_p != 0) else
    `uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", "FILE OPENED FAILED")


`endif  //MY_MACROS_SV
```

I  to call this macro from different classes (sequenece, driver, etc..) by:

```
`my_fatal("FATAL ERROR", "FILE OPENED FAILED")
```

When I try to compile this I got the following error:

```
# ** Error: (vlog-13069) ** while parsing file included at ./sv/girobo2_pkg.sv(4 )
# ** at .\sv\my_macros.sv(13): near "assert": syntax error, unexpected assert , expecting class.
```

Comment: You aren't using id and msg arguments in your function

Answer (score 3):

With multi-line macros, you need to escape the newlines with a backslash:

```
`define my_fatal(id, msg ) \
      assert (file_p != 0) else \
    `uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", "FILE OPENED FAILED")
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 22.5.1 `define

In response to your (now-deleted) comment, I think you meant to use:

```
    `uvm_fatal(id, msg)
```

Comment: I meant to ` `uvm_fatal(condition, id, msg)`